# Matcher for argument String.class,byte[].class Junit

Tags: junit, mockito

I have a code like  `mRestAccess.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, byte[].class);` Now I want to test this using JUnit.

When I am writing `Mockito.doReturn(stringResponse).when(mRestAccess).exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class),                                      Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class),???????);`

What to write in place of ????????

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Mockito.eq` to test argument equality (using `equals`). For even more flexibility, `any(Class.class)` would work, but may not constrain the type parameter `T` enough to work for some Mockito syntax.

```
Mockito.doReturn(stringResponse)
    .when(mRestAccess)
    .exchange(
         Mockito.anyString(),
         Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class),
         Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class),
         Mockito.eq(byte[].class));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case with Spring's RestClient, exchange method, which asks for:

```
restClient.exchange(URI, HttpMethod, HttpEntity, String.class)
```

I solved it with:

```
ArgumentCaptor<URI> uriCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(URI.class);
ArgumentCaptor<HttpEntity> entityCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(HttpEntity.class);
ArgumentCaptor<HttpMethod> methodCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(HttpMethod.class);
verify(restTemplate, times(1)).exchange(
    uriCaptor.capture(),
    methodCaptor.capture(),
    entityCaptor.capture(),
    Mockito.eq(String.class));
```

Then you get the chance to inspect the values as well, besides intercepting the call.

You can also do, for example:

```
doReturn(new ResponseEntity<String>("it works...", 200))
    .when(restTemplate).exchange(
        ArgumentMatchers.eq(uri),
        ArgumentMatchers.eq(HttpMethod.GET),
        ArgumentMatchers.eq(httpEntity),
        Mockito.eq(String.class)
    );
```

Answer (score -2):

Use below statement to mock spring restTemplate using powermockito.

```
PowerMockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
     Matchers.anyString(), 
     Matchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
     Matchers.<HttpEntity<?>> any(),
     Matchers.any(Class.class)))
 .thenReturn(respEntity);
```

Refer this [link](http://www.kswaughs.com/2015/09/how-to-mock-spring-resttemplate-using.html) for detailed explanation.

Comment: Please explain why Powermockito is required here, when it's not in in the question's tags, and develop the answer further on-site rather than putting the explanation behind a link to your own website.